# bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId is not working on create/start when "don't keep activities" turn on

Tags: android

I am using `bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId`. I have tried putting it in onCreate and onStart. It works for the most part but it fails to actually display the bottom tab as selected, if "don't keep activities" is turned on in developer options and I exit out of the app and re-enter it.

Update: I even tried this with example boilerplate code from https://androidwave.com/bottom-navigation-bar-android-example/ and it still failed

Example:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);
    bottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId(bottomNavigation.getMenu().getItem(0).getItemId());
    openFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance("", ""));
  }
```

The fragment displayed switches back to the home fragment, but the displayed "selected" tab is still the previous one. This only happens if "don't keep activities" is turned on.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting right ID with `bottomNavigation.getMenu().getItem(0).getItemId()`?. Just use  `bottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.yourHomeItemid)`

Comment: I believe if it were not correct, then it wouldn't have displayed the home tab's fragment. Have you gotten it to work even when "don't keep activities" is turned on and you go out of the app and go back in?